# Numbers as factor after read.delim

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 A      B      C      D       
 1      2      3      4   
 E      F      G      H     
 5      6      7      8
```

I would like to subset only the numeric portion using the following code:

```
 sub_num = DF[sapply(DF, is.numeric)]
```

The problem is that the numbers are factors after reading the data.frame using `read.delim`. If I set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` the numbers are characters. 
This may be a basic problem but I'm not able to solve it.

Comment: use as.character first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following instead

```
 sub_num <- DF[!is.na(as.numeric(sapply(DF, as.character)))[1:ncol(DF)], ]
 #     V1 V2 V3 V4
 #   2  1  2  3  4
 #   4  5  6  7  8
```

---

As for your `sapply` statement, `sapply(DF, is.numeric)`, in order to work correctly, it would need `as.character`

```
sapply(DF, function(X) is.numeric(as.character(X)))
```

But that would not index your DF as you would expect